Query for new user stories daily
I need to create an Azure Devops dashboard that will show how many User Stories we create on a daily basis and what the close rate is.
I have tried to create a query using 'created date' but when i ran it, i am not getting the result for daily userstories.

Created Date >= @StartOfDay &
Work Item Type = User Story

